# Error when trying to switch window in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario which I'm clicking on a button and then a new window pops up.
Now, I can't find elements on the pop up window, so I'm trying to switch to the new window\pop up.

I have tried doing that but getting an error:

```
_webdriver.SwitchTo().Window("0bd0568d-df1f-4472-b20b-842e03d412bd");
```

the error I'm getting is :

> NoSuchWindowException : No Window Found

I have found the window id by running the following:

```
foreach (string handle in _webdriver.WindowHandles)
{
    string popup = _webdriver.SwitchTo().Window(handle).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WindowHandle` changes every time you open window, so you can't specifie it like that. Use the loop each time you want to switch.

In addition, `SwitchTo().Window(handle)` returns `IWebDriver` instance, not window id. Use `driver.CurrentWindowHandle` for this.

```
// get the current active window
string parentHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

// open new window

// switch to the new window
foreach (string handle in driver.WindowHandles)
{
    if (!handle.Equals(parentHandle))
    {
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The window handle's string value is generated dynamically at runtime and thus different every time you run your test.

You should look for `driver.CurrentWindowHandle` in `driver.WindowHandles` and then switch to the next one. Although this might cause problems when testing on Opera or Android.

```
bool bFound = false;
foreach (string windowHandle in driver.WindowHandles)
{
    if (bFound)
    {
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandle);
        break;
    }
    bFound = windowHandle == driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
}
```